# Custom widget is not showing up on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm very new to java swing and interface creation. So, I'm supposed to create a orange square on JFrame. So, I tried this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Demo extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(20,50,100,100);
    }
}
public class Example implements ActionListener {
    public void atom() {
        Demo d = new Demo();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.atom();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

But the square is not showing up and I couldn't find, why is that. Can anyone guide me.

Comment: Please consider reading a tutorial or two. Guessing is never a good heuristic for learning to program.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add "d" widget to frame's content pane.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Demo extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(20,50,100,100);
    }
}
public class Example implements ActionListener {
    public void atom() {
        Demo d = new Demo();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        frame.getContentPane().add(d); //      
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.atom();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

[More information](http://leepoint.net/JavaBasics/gui/gui-commentary/guicom-60-contentpane.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @sudsparrowhawk

Answer (score 1):

After creating the frame, add d panel to it :

```
         frame.getContentPane().add(d);
```

Please refer to this tutorial: [How to Use Panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html//)